# Text editor which saves folded states

Tags: text, sublimetext3

I am currently working in a file that has over 900 lines of code. One big struggle I am facing is manually having to close every single loop, function definition, ... . For the moment I am using Sublime Text 3. (I am willing to change to any other text editor if needed.) The goal would be that when I open up the text file, it would have the loops etc automatically closed like it was when I last saved. Is this possible?

Comment: When you open a file it is always like when last saved! Are you looking for an auto correction software?

Comment: Check this: https://superuser.com/questions/801357/sublime-text-3-automatically-close-html-tags

Comment: No I am not looking for an auto correction software. Whenever I load my file all the loops are opened automatically, even tho I had the file saved while the loops were closed. This is a huge time-waste which I am trying to eliminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/)** editor (free, open source) saves folded states to history, restores them later from history file.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code does save the folded state (I'm sure other editors do it as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `Edit>Code Folding>Fold All`.

[image]

This will fold all functions in your code.

In order to save the fold state, you can use a very popular package called [BufferScroll](https://github.com/titoBouzout/BufferScroll).

Good luck!

**Edit:** fixed BufferScroll link.